# Go code organisation best practice

Tags: go, code-organization

After reading [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization), and watching  this [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCsL89YtqCs), I just want to ask:

- Is having multiple directories in the `GOPATH` variable environment considered a good practice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about good or bad practice. It's about different needs. Many developers can live with a single path in their GOPATH. Others have special needs and for them the multiple-path GOPATH is a solution.

Comment: 'special needs', can you provide some examples ?

Comment: @tarrsalah: For example, from [Third-party Packages](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/GOPATH): _"It is useful to have two GOPATH entries. One for a location for 3rd party goinstalled packages, and the second for your own projects. List the 3rd party GOPATH first, so that goinstall will use it as a default destination. Then you can work in the second GOPATH directory and have all your packages be importable by using the "go" command, goinstall, or a GOPATH-aware 3rd party build tool like gb."_

Comment: Thanks, I had to see the wiki before asking such a question.